# Measuring time with ATMEGA168

Tags: c, time, atmega

I am looking for ATMEGA168 timers examples to measure the duration of a function, however somehow all examples I found are more related to "deadlines" to execute a function. [See this](http://www.engblaze.com/microcontroller-tutorial-avr-and-arduino-timer-interrupts/).

How can I measure for how long a pin was high?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just before calling the target function, zero a global variable, start a timer.  with the timer interrupt handler incrementing a global variable each time the timer overflows.

after returning from the target function, stop the timer, multiply the global variable by the timer duration, add the partial duration in the timer counter.  calculate the elapsed time taking into account how fast the timer counts.